# Observable.publish() doesn't call onCompleted() on observers that subscribe after the source Observable is done

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm trying to get an `Observable` to share its emissions with all the subscribers, so that it would be subscribe()d to exactly once.
I tried using `Observable.publish()`, but it appears that subscribers to the published `Observable` don't receive any termination messages( `onCompleted()` and possibly `onError()`) if they subscribe after the source `Observable` is done. Here is a piece of code to demonstrate that:

```
static <T> Observer<T> printObserver(String name) {
    return new Observer<T>() {
        @Override public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println(name + ": onCompleted()");
        }
        @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(name + ": onError( " + e + " )");
        }
        @Override public void onNext(T value) {
            System.out.println(name + ": onNext( " + value + " )");
        }
    };
}
public void testRxPublishConnect() throws Exception {
    Observable<Integer> sourceObservable = Observable.range(1, 5);
    ConnectableObservable<Integer> sharedObservable = sourceObservable.publish();
    sharedObservable.subscribe(printObserver("Observer #1"));
    sharedObservable.connect();
    sharedObservable.subscribe(printObserver("Observer #2"));
}
```

This is what gets printed:

```
Observer #1: onNext( 1 )
Observer #1: onNext( 2 )
Observer #1: onNext( 3 )
Observer #1: onNext( 4 )
Observer #1: onNext( 5 )
Observer #1: onCompleted()
```

Note that `Observer #2` doesn't receive `onCompleted()`.
I don't think this is the desired behavior. Am I missing something?
I tried it in RxJava versions 1.0.8 and 1.0.14 with the same result.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wrote the same code for Rx.Net. It prints a 'Observer#2: OnCompleted()' message (in addition to the ones for Observer #1), which is what I expected from publish()/Publish().

Answer (score 1):

Try `.share()` which is `.publish().refCount()`.

Comment: That was my first approach. The problem is, the source Observable will be subscribed to again after all subscribers unsubscribe  (or after the source Observable finishes, which automatically unsubscribes all subscribers) and a new subscriber subscribes.

Comment: And to be clear, using PublishSubject solves my problem. I just find the behavior of .publish() weird.

Comment: Righto, excuse me not reading your question fully, I just threw this up in a spare minute. I think you should update your version of RxJava as a number of important fixes have gone in since that version (now on 1.0.14 I think).

Comment: I tried 1.0.14 too. The result was the same. I'm gonna update the question to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. If you call `connect()` in this case, your subscriber will receive all events from the start. If a terminated `publish` would terminate its child subscribers immediately, you likely couldn't observe values because once connected, `publish` ticks away its source slowly if there are no subscribers to it.

Comment: You mean the Observable that is the result of .publish(), if the source Observable is done, unsubscribes its subscribers immediately without calling onError() or onNext()? Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'publish ticks away its source slowly if there are no subscribers to it'?

Comment: In other terms, once the publish has started and all subscribers are gone, it drops source values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure this is the expected behavior. I'm not sure about RxJava, but in most of the implementations of the publish&subscribe pattern that I know of, the default behavior for an observable is to publish events to subscribers and forget about them. This means that notifications are not 'retro-active' (i.e. subscribers don't get to know anything about the events emitted in the past).

Also, from the [Observable Contract (section 'multiple observers') of the RxJava documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) :

`If a second observer subscribes to an Observable that is already emitting items to a first observer, it is up to the Observable whether it will thenceforth emit the same items to each observer ...  There is no general guarantee that two observers of the same Observable will see the same sequence of items`.

Comment: that's true about onNext() notifications. That isn't (to the best of my knowledge) true about onError() and onCompleted() notifications. To make sure, I checked PublishSubject, and it always gives onCompleted() notifications to subscribers, even if onCompleted() was called long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Publish works by building a list of all subscribers then once `connect()` is called it starts producing data to all subscribers in it's subscriber list. This means all the subscribers have to be known before calling connect. Here's how you would use `publish()` or possibly more preferable the `publish(Func1<Observable<T>, Observable<R>>)` overload.

Known number of subscribers: Publish

Func closing over all subscriptions.

```java
observableStream.publish(new Func1<Observable<Integer>, Observable<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Integer> call(Observable<Integer> subject) {
        Observable<Integer> o1 = subject.doOnNext(somework1());
        Observable<Integer> o2 = subject.doOnNext(somework2());
        return Observable.merge(o1, o2);
    }
});
```

Manual call to connect and subscribe:

```java
ConnectableObservable<Integer> subject = observableStream.publish();
subject.subscribe(somework1());
subject.subscribe(somework2());
subject.connect();
```

If you don't know how many subscribers you'll have then you can window the inputs to manageable chunks and then publish your inputs over your collection of `Transformer`s.

Unknown number of subscribers: Window

```java
final Set<Transformer<Integer, String>> transformers = new HashSet<>();
observableStream
    .window(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 1000)
    .flatMap(new Func1<Observable<Integer>, Observable<String>>(){
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(Observable<Integer> window) {
            return window.publish(new Func1<Observable<Integer>, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(Observable<Integer> publish) {
                    Observable<Observable<String>> workObservables = Observable.from(transformers)
                        .map(new Func1<Transformer<Integer, String>, Observable<String>>(){
                            @Override
                            public Observable<String> call(Transformer<Integer, String> transformer) {
                                return publish.compose(transformer);
                            }});
                    return Observable.merge(workObservables);
                }});
        }})
    .subscribe();
```

There is a third option. You could use `observable.cache()` but this will hold all input data from that observable stream in memory so you want to be careful with how you use that. In that case you'll probably end up windowing anyway to control the bounds of your cached subject.

Comment: I don't want any caching or windowing or anything. My expectation is that an Observable should send termination notifications to its subscribers if it's not going to emit any more items. In other words, it should be OK for an Observable to skip onNext() notifications, but not onError() or onCompleted() notifications.

Comment: Francisco's answer is correct in that a publish subject streams events to the child subscriber(s). If a subscribe takes place after connect then it will not receive any events (including the terminal signals). My answer tries to give you ways to use these apis given the constraints of having to subscribe all observers before connecting.

Comment: By this: 'If a subscribe takes place after connect then it will not receive any events (including the terminal signals)' do you mean in the piece of code in my question? Because if the observable emits items after subscribe, the observers do receive them. I tested it with Observable.interval().

Comment: And the documentation of publish() clearly suggests otherwise (take a look at the diagram): http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/publish.html

Comment: The marble diagram you have linked shows both observers subscribing before the connect. You are welcome to file a github issue on the project but I believe this was intentional behavior. Observable.interval is effectively an infinite observable and does not complete on its own. They have very different semantics.

Comment: Note that in the diagram there are 3 observers, the middle one subscribes after connect(). About Observable.interval(), my bad, I didn't explain it correctly, it was actually something like Observable.interval(...).take(5).

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. This example shows data and events streaming to any subscriber that is subscribed before the event is emitted to the subject. The 3rd subscribe takes place before the blue marble and thus it receives that event. The subject itself doesn't hold state with respects to terminal or next events. I'm not defending that design choice and it is certainly something we are reviewing in the process of building RxJava 2.0. If you want to be a part of that discussion I recommend filing an issue.

Comment: OK, thanks for your response. The weird thing is that PublishSubject (and other Subjects I presume) does hold terminal state. They must have completely different implementations then.